# Could not install PEAR on Windows 7 with WAMP

Tags: windows-7, installation, wamp, pear

After I changed the default location of pear.ini, and changed my `php.ini` to `phar.require_hash -> off`, I still got the following error

11.Name of configuration file: `e:\`

12.Path to CLI `php.exe`: `E:\software\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10`

1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue:
Beginning install...

PHP Fatal error:  `Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::set()` in `phar://E:/software/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start.php on line 301`

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. `{main}() E:\software\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\pear\go-pear.phar:0`

PHP   2. `require_once() E:\software\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\pear\go-pear.phar:1236`

PHP   3. `PEAR_Start_CLI->run() phar://E:/software/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/pear/go-pear.phar/index.php:7`

PHP   4. `PEAR_Start->doInstall() phar://E:/software/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/pear/
go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start/CLI.php:57`

```
Fatal error: 
Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::set() in phar://E:/software/wa
mp/bin/php/php5.3.10/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start.php on line 301

Call Stack:
0.0273    1174752   1. {main}() E:\software\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\pear\go-p
ear.phar:0

0.0276    1171720   2. require_once('phar://E:/software/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.
10/pear/go-pear.phar/index.php') E:\software\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\pear\go-pear
.phar:1236

0.0622    5496272   3. PEAR_Start_CLI->run() phar://E:/software/wamp/bin/php
/php5.3.10/pear/go-pear.phar/index.php:7

102.2854    5508080   4. PEAR_Start->doInstall() phar://E:/software/wamp/bin/p
hp/php5.3.10/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start/CLI.php:57
```

btw, I used wamp installer on my windows 7, so I do not have go-pear.bar, instead, I downloaded the go-pear.phar, and run it like:php `pear/go-pear.phar`, thanks

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? i am also facing the same problem

Comment: @Suriya Have you resolved this issue? i am also facing the same problem

Comment: @WebDeveloper, i posted my solution, i hope it will help

Answer (score 4):

Here is how i resolved my issue. May be helpful for some one.

I installed pear for `local` scope. i am not trying with system wide since i faced some permission issue to edit the `pear.ini`.

I followed the article below to get it done.

[PEAR, PHPUnit](http://amiworks.co.in/talk/installing-pear-and-phpunit-on-wamp-and-windows-7/)

I downloaded the `go-pear` file from the following url,

[go-pear.phar](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2012/05/10/getting-pear-working-on-windows-7/)

I rebooted my system to make the registry settings are applied properly before proceeding the `PHPUnit` installation.

**Note:**
`Pear channel` for `symfony` has been moved from `pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com` to `pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com`.